# How set same fonts style of chapter in "Glenn" "fncychap"

Tags: fncychap

How set same fonts style of chapter in "Glenn" "fncychap"
[image]

code :

```
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
\ChTitleVar{\bf\centering}
\setlength{\headsep}{1cm}
```

Comment: The chapter is set in `\textsf{\MakeUppercase{...}}` and the title in `\textbf{\MakeUppercase{...}}`.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the font of the `CHAPTER` string with `\ChNameVar` which works similar to `\ChTitleVar`. If you also want to change the font of the number, there is `\ChNumVar` too.

Also there is no point in using `\centering` here because `fncychap` takes care of aligning the text. `\bf` is deprecated and no longer provided by modern document classes, use `\bfseries` instead.
Additionally the `\Ch...Var` arguments should probably contain some sizing command like `\large`, `\Large`, `Huge`, .... Otherwise the size of the element in undefined. In your example your title has size `\Huge`. So you can get this effect with:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[Glenn]{fncychap}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
\ChNameVar{\bfseries\Huge\rmfamily}
\ChTitleVar{\bfseries\Huge\rmfamily}
\setlength{\headsep}{1cm}
\begin{document}
\chapter{One}
\chapter{Two}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: is it possible to make chapter word with same font size of "ONE" word

Comment: I added some sizing and family selection, but you might want to use a bigger size for the number to keep the original appearance.